# Sort my post by ascendant order (time)

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

After struggling a lot, I finally was able to display the blog entries in my `index.php`, but they are ordered with the newer ones on the bottom and the older ones on top.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
            $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=posts','root','');

            $cmd = $connect->query('SELECT * FROM posts');

            $resultado = $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

             foreach($resultado as $item):
                ?>
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="post-body">
                        <a href="" class="post-title"><?php echo $item['titulo']?></a>
                        <div class="title-separator"></div>
                        <p class="post-body-text"><?php echo $item['cuerpo'] ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-body-footer">
                        <img src="images/posted.png" alt="" class="posted"> <span class="posted-text">Posted on </span><span class="date"><?php echo $item['fecha']?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
             endforeach;
        ?>
```

Comment: So, `ORDER BY col ASC/DESC`? Take your pick. If you do `ORDER BY col` it defaults to ASC.

Comment: Should I make a prepared statement?

Comment: Sure, if you want to.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the boy scout coding school, always be prepared

Comment: No that's fine. It's been answered in comments. You may as well delete the question. I was glad to have been of help.

Comment: @Dagon *Aye,* that's moi.

Comment: I'll leave it here for other people asking the question! Thanks again :)

Comment: Then I'll post an answer then.

Comment: @pedritoalfonso I posted an answer as per your request, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to "order" your data in the fashion you wish to have them listed as, you can use
`ORDER BY your_column` with a choice of either `ASC` or `DESC`.

`ORDER BY` defaults to `ASC` if omitted from the query.

I.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY titulo DESC
```

Consult:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Example pulled from the manual:

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
```

Comment: @Dagon The OP didn't want to delete the question, so I may as well post something before somebody else just "pops in" code with no explanation.